# Simple Rails/MySQL Query generates a strange result

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
1.8.7 :011 > User.find(:first).id
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` LIMIT 1
 => 1 

1.8.7 :012 > User.find(:first, :select => 'id')
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT id FROM `users` LIMIT 1
 => #<User id: 2>
```

From my side... iam totaly confused. It should give me the User ID 1 on both querys right? What i know is that the first user in the Database has the ID 1 and i know this "problem/strange result" is related to MySQL.

```
SELECT * FROM `users` LIMIT 1;
= 1

SELECT id FROM `users` LIMIT 1;
= 2

SELECT id FROM `users` ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1;
= 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The results from a select aren't ordered until you explicitly order them. There is no specific "first" record, unless you add an `ORDER BY` clause telling it by which criteria it should consider a record to be "first".

In Ruby specifically, the `.first` method (or `find(:first)`) won't apply any ordering, so the results will be (essentially) random. If you need the "first" record to be the same each time, you need to order the results:

```
User.order(:id).first
```

This is (somewhat oddly) contrasted by the `.last` method, which *will* apply an `order(:id)` automatically.

Comment: Really? First always returned the first record in DB for me, good to know this! :) Deleted my answer, don't want to confuse anyone.

Comment: @Kaeros This is coincidence. If your select ever gets complex enough to involve an index, it will stop yielding up the record with the lowest id as "first".